# BBcode quote - forum

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

can you please help me. I have two code for convert quote. So I want get from html to these `[quote=user name]TEXT[/quote]`

```
$replace[] = '/\[quote\=(.*?)\]((?:(?!\[\/?quote\]).)*)\[\/quote\]/is';
$rewrite[] = '<blockquote><div class="msg_quote"><span id="quote_from">$1 je napisal/a</span><span class="citiranje_text">$2</span></div></blockquote>';

$change = preg_replace($replace, $rewrite, $text_message);
```

Comment: Use [PHP’s built-in BBCode library](http://php.net/bbcode).

Comment: Watch out, the "built in" library is actually a PECL module.  It's not built anywhere by default.

Answer (score 0):

Following pattern would work,

```
preg_replace("/\[quote=(.*?)](.*?)\[\/quote]/", $r, $sub);
```

Comment: 1. Your regex `\[quote=(.*?)](.*?)\[\/quote]` matches `[quote=user name]TEXT [and my dog] [/quote]` ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/bN8bY7)), so why are you commenting on mine?... and 2. Did you downvote me?

Comment: Ok now i tested preg_replace("/\[quote=(.*?)](.*?)\[\/quote]/", $r, $sub); and it's working but when i put multiple [quote this dosn't work. Please help

Comment: what do you mean by `multiple [quote`? provide example.

Comment: When i click 3x on quote dont' t change to html